# Using twice the same cell with indirect function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

This is the fomula I would like to use to sum value from two cells:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("sheet1!B"&J3)+INDIRECT("sheet1!B"&(value_cell_J3+5)))
```

I am not able to set a the **(value_cell_J3+5)**

I know I can create a new column as *=J3+5* to be linked to the formula, but I have too much column to create to follow this way

eg when cell J3=100 I need this: sheet1!B**100**+sheet1!B**105**

Comment: Is J3 in Sheet1 ?

Comment: No, in J3 there is the value of the row to sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer INDEX as it is not volatile, but essentially you would just add 5 to J3:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,J3)+INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,J3+5)
```

Plus the SUM() is not needed if you use the `+`